Creating double sampling plans
I am trying to create double sampling plans. The product has to meet a reliability of at least 90% with 95% confidence. Assuming binomial distribution, I can create a single sampling plan by testing 29 samples and accepting at 0 failures and rejecting at >0 failures.
How do I create double sampling plans?
I stole the image from the question: Average sample size for curtailed sampling plan

